# Change a column only if a certain condition is met, otherwise don't modify it

Tags: r, if-statement, dataframe, dplyr

Sample dataframe:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(x = runif(10), 
                 y = runif(10),
                 group = factor(sample(LETTERS[1:10], 10, replace = TRUE)))
```

I want to set `x` equal to `y` if `group == "A"`, otherwise I don't want to modify it. For now I found this solution:

```
df %<>% mutate(x =  ifelse(group == "A", y, x))
```

Is this a good solution or are there better/faster ways?

Comment: Why do you need to mutate? Can't you just do: `df$x <- ifelse(group=="A", y, x)`?

Comment: try your code: it won't work. `Error in ifelse(group == "A", y, x) : object 'group' not found`. You probably meant `df$x <- ifelse(df$group=="A", df$y, df$x)`, but I'm not sure this last one is simpler/faster than the  `mutate` one. It **could be faster**, maybe, on a bigger dataframe, but on my real use case the two methods seem to be equivalent.

Comment: Sorry, forgot my `df$`s there. How exactly are you looking to improve upon what you already have? The `mutate` seems a bit redundant when `ifelse()` alone would work, especially considering that it's a base solution.

Comment: @seeellayewhy that's also true. I don't know how I could have improved on what I had, because I don't know R well enough. I was asking you gurus if my solution made sense or not :) your comment that it may be overkill is also welcome. I may be a bit too quick to resort to `dplyr` sometimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that is a good solution

You could alternately use dplyr's `if_else`.

There is also `case_when` in dplyr but that seems overkill here.

Also

```
df %>% mutate(x = y * (A == "group") + x * (A != "group")
```

but I would not use that approach here.

`case_when` and `if_else` are dplyr functions so if you were thinking of using this code with a database backend then they would more likely work than non-dplyr functions.

**Update:** I had been thinking about `replace` as well but in this situation it does not work as nicely. You would have to write:

```
df %>% mutate(x = replace(x, group == "A", y[group =="A"]))
```

which seems quite ugly.

Comment: I like the idea of for `if_else` and I will switch to that. I don't know much about `replace`. Would you recommend it as a better solution? If so, I'll go through the help page.

Comment: Have moved comment to answer.